# How to Open a url in new tab that changes the source location also and opens in new tab | Fail "target_blank"

Tags: javascript, php

i know u may think this as silly question but currently iam facing issue with a url, which when  i try to open in new tab, it changes the current source url also and opens another url in new tab ,
Example , i want to open this url in new tab , http://dolohen.com/afu.php?zoneid=2458044
Now if you go to : https://www.ytsubme.com/_/eePEz/ , and click on the "DOWNLOAD" ad image , it will redirect users to new tab but also change the current url also , 
i tired using  **"target="_blank"** attribute , still not working , here is the code  : https://pastebin.com/AZZpVz6M or

`<?php
    echo  '<a href="http://dolohen.com/afu.php?zoneid=2458044" "target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/x3KHLmV/27-91918-Static-Red-Button-300x250.png"  /></a>';
?>`

Comment: Change **"target="_blank"** to **target="_blank"**. I mean: there is an extra double quotes before **target**. Probably this is not your problem. But it is wrong to stay this way.

Comment: hi stat, thanks for suggestion , still its not working

Comment: This matter you describe use to happen when you have "two commands" working together. For example you have an image inside an **<a>** and, at the same time, an **onclick** property on that image. Check if this is not happening.

Comment: Also and maybe more important: check with abother url, another link. The ad you are opening may be the cause for that. It may possess an internal routine to open a blank or to change actual url. Links made by javascript use to have this behavior.

Comment: the rel="noopener noreferrer" tag worked bro !

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that the `dolohen` URL is exploiting the [**target blank vulnerability**](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/), which you're not protecting against. This would allow them to redirect **your** tab with [**`window.opener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener).

To guard against this, you should add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to your link:

```
<a href="http://dolohen.com/afu.php?zoneid=2458044" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
```

In addition to this, you had a leading `"` on `target`, which has been removed in the above.

Comment: hi obsi, Thanks man working now ♥ really thank you soooo much bro